# Why is conversion not applied?

Tags: spring, scala, implicit-conversion, jdbctemplate

I'd like to use scala's implicit conversion in spring `JdbcTemplate`.

`JdbcTemplate` has following 2 methods :

```
jdbcTemplate.update(String sql, Object... params)               // (1)

jdbcTemplate.update(String sql, PreparedStatementSetter pss)    // (2)
```

`PreparedStatementSetter` is just an interface, and I'd like to just pass a function value to `JdbcTemplate`. That means I want to change it to be

JdbcTemplate.update(sql: String, setter: PreparedStatement => Unit)  // (3)

What I did is create `RichJdbcTemplate`, as a wrapper of `JdbcTemplate`:

```
class RichJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate: JdbcTemplate) {

  def update(sql: String, setter: PreparedStatement => Unit) {
    jdbcTemplate.update(sql, new PreparedStatementSetter() {
      def setValues(ps: PreparedStatement) {
        setter(ps)
      }
    })
  }
}
```

And I expected that every time if I call `jdbcTemplate.update(sql, setter: PreparedStatement => Unit)`
there would be an implicit conversion between `jdbcTemplate` and `RichJdbcTemplate`.  But actually it does not do implicit conversion here.  Because here the method conforms with the signature of `jdbcTemplate.update(String sql, Object... params)`.  That's why there's no implicit conversion here. Is there any other solution that could achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Can anyone explain why this question got closed?  It seems like a perfectly reasonable question to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just give your method a different name; call it `updateWithFunction` or something.

As you mention, the issue is that Scala doesn't look for an implicit conversion because it find a method with the correct name and correct parameter types directly on `JdbcTemplate`.  The way around it is to use a name that it *won't* find on `JdbcTemplate`.

You could also do the wrapping explicitly, `new RichJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate).update(...)`, but that's uglier.

Answer (score 3):

Rename the update method to something else. Define an implicit conversion in an object and import into scope:

```
object MyImplConversions {
  implicit def toRichJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate: JdbcTemplate) =
    new RichJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate)
}
```